# Filling DataGridView does not work

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I try to fill `DataGridView` with data from `DataTable`

Here is my method which executes query (this method is in other class called `MySQL`)

```
Public Function WykonajZapytanie(sql As String) As DataTable

        Dim dt As DataTable

        Try
            Connect()
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
            dt = New DataTable()
            da.Fill(dt)

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            ...
        Catch ex As Exception
            ...
        Finally
            Disconnect()
        End Try

        Return dt
    End Function
```

And here is a method which should populates datagridview from DataTable:

```
Public Sub WyswietlNoweZamowienia()

    Dim mySql As New MySQL
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM KLIENCI"

    dt = mySql.WykonajZapytanie(sql)

    Try
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt   'Here it doesn't populate dgv

    Catch ex As Exception
        ...
    End Try
End Sub
```

I don't have any error or something. The code just does not fill the DataGridView. What I am doing wrong?

PS. Connection to database works fine.

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns? It should be set to true as per default, but...

Comment: I added `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True` but it didn't help

Comment: are you sure there is data in the datatable?

Comment: @Plutonix, yes I'm sure, because `MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows(0).Item(0))` returns a value

Comment: try a DataGridView1.DataBind() after your DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

Comment: @Kritner, "The DataBind method is not needed in winforms". I use WinForm so I even don't have this method available

Comment: Should probably mention that in your tags or post somewhere :P

Comment: Did you see the column names on the empty grid or it is just a blank square?

Comment: I see blank square as before

Comment: That's really strange because this is the exact behavior you could see if the AutoGenerateColumn is false (an empty dark gray square). Also, in a simple snippet on LinqPad i have created manually a DataGridView and filled its datasource with a valid datatable without a problem. I would take a bit of time to look at every property different from the default set on the grid designer and then look if something in code changes these defaults. (also switching datasources)

Comment: Just for debugging, if you know the columns exactly, try having your datatable dt with columns 1,2,3 that you have created, and then use dt.rows.add(value from sql, value, value). It breaks up the process more, and maybe stepping it through that way might give you more clues.

Comment: Try this, delete the current datagridview and create another one with the name "DataGridView1". Don't change any other properties, leave it as default. Then see what happens. By default, it should fill in.

Comment: @Steve, wow it helped! But the really funny thing is that I really did not change any properties of DataGridView1. I haven't even looked at `Properties Window` so I couldn't change...

Comment: Must have changed something accidently when focus was in the wrong spot. It happens often. Glad you got it fixed. enjoy

Comment: Glad you have helped me, thanks a lot!